# Save a piece of xml is a new xml DOMParser Java

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Code</title>
        <item>
            <title>Java</title>
            <link>java.com</link>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I want  save in new xml but I don't now how to save this is new Document because I am trying:

```
File file = new File("staff.xml");
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();                           
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("New.xml"));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

and i save doc to new xml consequence I have the same xml in two files. How I can take only node   and save this in new xml?

Comment: Well, which node do you want to save? You can select elements by name with e.g. `getElementsByTagName("item")` or use XPath to select nodes.

Comment: I want to save :                                                                                                  '<item>
            <title>Java</title>
            <link>java.com</link>
            <id>1</id>
        </item>'                                                                                                  the new xml

Comment: Then create `new DOMSource(doc.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0))` instead of `new DOMSource(doc)`.

Comment: Thanks!! It works great!! I made  : `DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc.getElementsByTagName("item").item(0));
  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("NOWY.xml"));
  transformer.transform(domSource, result);`